# Create subclass constructors with a given number of arguments in Java

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class `SuperClass`, which simply stores different objects. It should contain the number of objects it stores, and store the objects in order in some type of list (currently thinking about using an array or an `ArrayList`, but I'm open to changing that).

I then want to create subclasses which only store a certain number of objects. For example, I might have `SubClassA`, `SubClassB`, and `SubClassC`, which take 2, 3, and 2 objects, respectively. I think the correct approach would be to store the number of objects each subclass takes as a `public static int`.

However, I don't want to write new constructors for each subclass, because there will be quite a few of these subclasses. Also, they all follow the same template: take a given number (the `static int`) of objects and store them in a list. Is there any way to do this in Java?

To be clear, I am not open to modifying the class structure, because I need to apply different rules to each class outside of the class body. If there is no possible way to design this such that multiple subclasses take the same number of arguments (e.g. `SubClassA` and `SubClassC` could not both exist), then I will accept a solution that does not allow for duplicate number of arguments. (Hopefully I could then do something like `SubClassA` extends `SubClass<2 args>` and `SubClassC` extends `SubClass<2 args>`. If not, I guess I'll just store another data member to ID the object, but that would be quite inelegant.)

Comment: Can you please add some sample code to your question? It is way easier to figure out what you mean and work on possible solutions that way.

Answer (score 0):

Make `SuperClass` abstract with a `protected` constructor that takes an array of objects, or rather a vararg.

Then have each subclass declare a constructor that accepts exactly the number of objects it supports. No need for `public static int` constant.

*Example*

```
public abstract SuperClass {
    private final Object[] objs;

    protected SuperClass(Object... objs) {
        this.objs = objs;
    }
    public int size() {
        return this.objs.length;
    }
    public Object get(int index) {
        return this.objs[index];
    }
    // Other methods
}

public final class SubClassA extends SuperClass {
    public SubClassA(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        super(obj1, obj2);
    }
    // Other methods
}

public final class SubClassB extends SuperClass {
    public SubClassB(Object obj1, Object obj2, Object obj3) {
        super(obj1, obj2, obj3);
    }
    // Other methods
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks! Would there be any way to do it without writing a separate constructor for each new class?

Comment: If you don't have a constructor, how would the `objX` values get into the class?

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to create a constructor for all the classes at once, but that doesn't seem possible. The constructor for each would still exist, you just don't have to write it every time.

Comment: But since each subclass is different, the constructors will be different, e.g. in the number of parameters (and their types?). Besides, the 3 lines of constructor code is likely minor, compared to the "different rules" logic each class will have, so what is the big deal?